# In Python, how can I get the Unix timestamp of the day before?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I'm in PST time.  I want to get 2 timestamps:

1. the beginning of yesterday
2. the end of yesterday

These timestamps should be the same no matter what time it is currently.

How can I do this with Python?

Do I have to use the `datetime` object, and then transform it to timestamp?

Comment: You don't _have_ to use a `datetime` object, but… why would you not _want_ to?

Comment: What do you mean by "beginning of yesterday"

Comment: How could the timestamps be the same if they are for two different points in time?

Comment: And by "end of yesterday" do you mean "beginning of today"? Or do you mean one (second?/millisecond?/nanosecond?) before midnight?

Comment: @MattJohnson: For your first question, I don't think there's anything unclear: the timestamps will be different if the _day_ changes, but at different times in _the same day_ they will always be the same. For the second, if he wants a half-open range here, I don't think he needs to state so explicitly, since that's what Python uses consistently, and what people usually use for faking continuous time ranges with discrete time values.

Comment: @abarnert - I'm still confused.  Maybe it's just the wording.  I understand about half-open intervals.  I just don't understand how two different points in time (one at the beginning of the day, one at the end) can be expected to have the same exact timestamp.

Comment: @MattJohnson: He's saying the pair of timestamps returned at any given time should be the same as the pair of timestamps returned at any other time in the same day. Not the same as _each other_.

Comment: @abarnert - Thanks, that makes sense now.  So we're looking for "midnight to midnight" of the prior day in the local time zone, as long as midnight is valid.  Yes?

Comment: Do you have to deal with the days when the clocks spring forward and fall back?  They complicate what is otherwise doable because mostly you add 86399 seconds to the start time to get the end time, except when you need to add 86399±3600 seconds.  You might do better with an end time that is the start of the next day (86400±3600), and write your code to exclude the end time.  It avoids awkward questions about what happens during the last second before midnight.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I already suggested using a half-open range, both a few comments back and in my answer, because there's no other way to define a continuous time range, and DST doesn't really affect that. DST also doesn't affect you when you use a high-level time library—but if you try to do it with something low-level built on timestamps, you do have to take care of it. Again, that's explained in my answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To get `yesterday` I guess you can do this:

```
>>>import datetime
>>>yesterday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)
>>>unix_time= yesterday.strftime("%s") #Second as a decimal number [00,61] (or Unix Timestamp)
>>>print unix_time
'1372737600'
```

Comment: On python 2.7 this does not work for me.  It give a error with unix_time= yesterday.strftime("%s") and 00 with unix_time= yesterday.strftime("%S")

Comment: Caution should be given that this returns a *string* despite looking exactly like the  'number' it should be.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way to do this is with `datetime`. But you apparently want to avoid that for some strange reason. Well, you can use `time` or `calendar`, or various third-party libraries, or custom code instead.

Here it is with `time`:

```
import time

def yesterday():
    now = time.time()
    yday = time.localtime(now - 86400) # seconds/day
    start = time.struct_time((yday.tm_year, yday.tm_mon, yday.tm_mday, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, yday.tm_isdst))
    today = time.localtime(now)
    end = time.struct_time((today.tm_year, today.tm_mon, today.tm_mday, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, today.tm_isdst))
    return time.mktime(start), time.mktime(end)
```

If you run this during a leap second, on a platform that tracks leap seconds, it will give today instead of yesterday. You can check for that easily (basically, if today == yesterday, subtract another day), but I don't think it's worth it.

Also, if you run this during DST crossover in a timezone where the crossover happens between midnight and 01:00 or 23:00 (depending on your hemisphere), it will get the wrong day. For example, in [Brazil](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=45), if you ran this code during the second 23:00-00:00 hour on 16 February 2013, it would return the start of the day that includes the time 24 hours ago… which is today, rather than yesterday. The same workaround works here.

Comment: Yes, there are time zones that transition as you described.  For example, [Brazil](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=45).

Comment: @MattJohnson: It looks like you're right; in Brazil, during the second 23:00-00:00 on 16 February, this code will return today instead of yesterday (assuming `is_dst` works right). Let me edit the answer. Thanks.

Comment: 1) [time.gmtime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.gmtime) takes one argument: seconds, not year, month, day. 2) If you state that the only correct answer is a half open range, this includes the 'off the end' value of the first moment of today. This is correct for `start < time_yesterday < end` but incorrect for any logic one may want to use using `end` and the named tuples of yesterday, like `end.tm_mon end.tm_day` etc 3) The OP did not say specifically he did not want to use datetime 4) Your logic will be off by the fraction of the second returned by `time.time()`

Comment: @thewolf: 1) sorry, that should be `struct_time`; fixed. 2) No, a half-open range is `start <= time < end`, not `start < time`. 3) The OP said "Do I have to use the DateTime object?" That implies that he doesn't want to use it. But, just in case I've inferred wrong, the very first sentence is "The obvious way to do this is with `datetime`." 4) If you mean the microsecond portion, no, that can't make any difference; HH:MM:SS.999999 is always on the same day as HH:MM:SS.000000. If you mean that `time.time()` doesn't run instantly… then so what?

Comment: @thewolf: Also, note that nobody's using `end`; he explicitly wants a _timestamp_, which is just a number, so that's what I'm returning. A pair of timestamps has to be interpreted as a half-open range; the only other alternative would be to return the previous real number to midnight of today, and there is no such thing as "the previous real number" by definition.